# My C# program does not initialize the Object how I think it has to according to the Object initialization order. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, initialization

I believe the Object Initialization order of C# goes like this:

- Derived static fields
- Derived static constructor
- Derived instance fields
- Base static fields
- Base static constructor
- Base instance fields
- Base instance constructor
- Derived instance constructor

Below you see a simple test program and the output it produces when I run it.

```
    public class UiBase
    {
        protected static string Something = "Hello";

        public UiBase()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Point : UiBase
    {
        private int X = -1;
        private int Y = -1;

        static Point()
        {
            Something = "Bar";
        }

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Point:{X}/{Y}/{Something}";
        }
    }

    public static class Program{
    public static void Main(){
        var x = new Point(2,1);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
on Console:
Point:-1/-1/Bar
Point:2/1/Bar
```

When I think about how it should happen according to the list above, I believe it should be like this:

1. Point static field (none in my case?)
2. Point static constructor -> sets Something to "Bar"
3. Point instance fields
4. Base static fields -> sets Something back to "Hello"?
   ...

However it does NOT set Something back to Hello which really confuses me. So how can I explain this? or is the Object Initialization different from what I stated?

Comment: What did you output in this line? `Console.WriteLine(` it won't compile

Comment: sorry copy pasta mistake. i corrected it

Comment: No, static constructors all come first, necessarily, before any object instance will be created.

Comment: static, base, derived.  Calling a virtual method in a constructor of a class that is not *sealed* is risky.  The C++ language is notable, it prevents methods from behaving virtual until the constructor finished running.  To prevent surprises like this one, albeit that programmers now tend to be stumped when you wanted the surprise.  C# doesn't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call a virtual member `ToString()` in base `UiBase` class constructor

```cs
Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
```

It's being called before `Point` constructor

```cs
public Point(int x, int y)
{
     X = x;
     Y = y;
}
```

`this` isn't fully initialized yet, you are getting `-1` in output. Since `ToString()` is virtual method, `Point.ToString()` is called, per [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual#remarks)

> The overriding member in the most derived class is called, which might
>   be the original member, if no derived class has overridden the member.

Static constructor is called automatically before the instance of `Point` is created or any static members are referenced (have a look at the [static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) for details)

```cs
static Point()
{
     Something = "Bar";
}
```

It'll overwrite `Something` from base class and you get `Bar` in output in both cases. `Something` is never set back to `Hello`, it's being overwritten only once.

`Something` field is entirely specific for `UiBase`, there is no copy in `Point` class, it's value will be changed everywhere. According to [static members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members)

> Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many
>   instances of the class are created.

If you print `UiBase.Something` after `Console.WriteLine(x);`, you'll get `Bar`, not the `Hello`. There is only one exception, for generic classes, but it's out of scope of your question.

In terms of execution order all field initializers run in order from derived class to base, and then all constructors run in order from base to derived (this is correct for instance members). I've added a steps for all your operations to see the actual order.

```cs
public class UiBase
{
    private static int temp = Step("uibase static field init");
    public static string Something = "Hello";

    private int _temp = Step("uibase instance field init");

    public static int Step(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        return 0;
    }

    public UiBase()
    {
        Step("uibase instance ctor");
        Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
    }
}

public class Point : UiBase
{
    private int _temp = Step("point instance field init");

    private int X = -1;
    private int Y = -1;

    static Point()
    {
        Step("point static ctor before");
        Something = "Bar";
        Step("point static ctor after");
    }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        Step("point instance ctor");

        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Point:{X}/{Y}/{Something}";
    }
}
```

the output will be the following

```
point static ctor before
uibase static field init
point static ctor after
point instance field init
uibase instance field init
uibase instance ctor
Point:-1/-1/Bar
point instance ctor
Point:2/1/Bar
```

The `Point` static constructor is invoked first (there is no static fields in `Point` class), then it'll 'ask' `UiBase` init a static fields, because accessing its `Something` value (it's set to `Hello`), after that `Something` is set to `Bar` and execution continues to instance initialization (again, `Something` never changes anymore) -  derived class fields, base class fields, base class constructor and derived class constructor.

I think, only first 3 lines can be confusing a little bit, but static initialization happens only once and before any instance initialization. The order of static initialization is determined by compiler based on your actual code.

Adding a `UiBase` static constructor can make the picture more clear actually, in this case `UiBase` static members will be initialized before `Point` static initialization.

Comment: yes but what about the order from my post? in the order it says clearly that derived static constructor is called before base static field init. So based on that I expect it to run the static ctor of point which changes Something to Bar and after that the base field Something gets initialized with the value "Hello". So why does it not happen as the order says? this would mean that the order is not correct?

Comment: _If static field variable initializers are present in the class of the static constructor, they will be executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration immediately prior to the execution of the static constructor._  `protected static string Something = "Hello";` is executed before static constructor. `UiBase` static initialization is called before `Point` static initialization, because `Point` inherits `UiBase`

Comment: so the order is wrong? this would mean it is derived static field->base static field->derived static ctor->derived instance fields-> base static ctor...?

Comment: Static initialization happens before any instance initialization

Comment: @MasterR8 I've added a steps in your code, you an see the actual order

Comment: Ok I get it know thank you :) Yes the first 3 lines got me confused.